# Separating the clickOnce setup.exe

Tags: installation, vsto, clickonce

I am trying to deploy the setup.exe that click once creates to users through sccm due to business practices.  The issue I am running into is that when I move the setup.exe out of the folder that contains the .VSTO, then the computer the setup.exe is being run on cannot find the VSTO. Is there anyway when publishing to have that setup.exe file look back at the file server that contains the VSTO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bootstrapper (setup.exe) just check for prerequisites before running a real installer app for installing the software. Running setup.exe separately doesn't make any sense.

There are two main ways of deploying Office applications:

1. [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019). It is used for centralized deployments like SCCM.
2. [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2019).

You may find various custom installers that may embed everything into a single setup.exe file. For example, you may take a look at [InstallShield](https://www.flexerasoftware.com/install/products/installshield.html) or [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html) .